# Overriding drawRect method in a UIView subclass & call it into another UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am a novice ios programmer and this is my first project.I am going to develop this project specifically for ipad. In this project i need to draw  several circles &  display data on it by parsing xml element.I have done the the circle drawing part by subclassing UIView class and overriding drawRect method. I load the UIView subclass in a UIViewcontroller via loadview method .Now what i need to do is

- Touch a circle and switch to another UIViewcontroller.

I am not sure how to switch to another UIViewcontroller because all of drawing and touch detecting code is in my UIView subclass.

A help will be appreciated

Comment: Till here looks good. you need to load  UIVC from your subclass where you drew circles.

Comment: Could please elaborate your answer. I mean i have loaded already the UIView subclass in  a UIViewcontroller. Now i need to switch to another UIViewcintroller after touch a circle in my UIView subclass.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a delegate method to tell the parent view controller that there was a touch, so it can present another view controller.

At the top of your `UIView` subclass header, add this:

```
@protocol MyCustomViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)customViewCircleTapped;

@end
```

Then, in your declaration of the view (the existing declaration you have of your custom view subclass):

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView

...

@property (weak) id<MyCustomViewDelegate> delegate;
```

After that, in your view controller, you need to set `view.delegate = self`, so the view can reference the view controller.

Then, in your view controller header, change your declaration to look like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyCustomViewDelegate>
```

then implement `customViewCircleTapped` in the view controller implementation:

```
- (void)customViewCircleTapped {
    ... // Open a view controller or something
}
```

Once you have done that, in the touch detection code in your view, you can add:

```
[self.delegate customViewCircleTapped];
```

What this does is gives your custom view the ability to tell its parent view controller that something has happened, by calling this method (you can change it and add arguments if you need to pass data), and then the view controller can open another view controller or perform some action based on this.

> View detects touches → Process touches → call `customViewCircleTapped` delegate method on view controller → view controller opens another view controller

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have done the view referencing to view controller part in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller as follows...                                                 iOSCircleView *viewDelegate =[[iOSCircleView alloc]init];
 viewDelegate.delegate = self; Is it ok?....rest of the thing have done according to your instructions.still it is not working

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your touch handling code in your view to make sure `[self.delegate customViewCircleTapped]` is being called. You need to call this method from your touch handling code, then in the implementation in your view controller add code to open another view controller or some other action.

Comment: Finally i have made it workable.just passed the delegate as parameter in the loadView method of the view controller. anyways i would take your answer as the accepted one.thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 0):

Provide the subclassed view with a delegate notifying the view is touched and in the delegate call in the mainVC do the push job

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do this is to send a message up the responder chain. This completely decouples the view from it's enclosing views and view controllers. So, when your circle view is tapped, it emits a "circle view was tapped message" to the responder chain--the first object on the responder chain that responds to that message (which don't know/care which one) will have it invoked. It's simple to implement.

You attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to your view with `-tapped:` as the action.

On your view, your tap action might look like this.

```
-(IBAction)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)g
{
    [ self sendAction:@selector( circleViewTapped: ) withObject:self ] ;
}
```

The `-sendAction:` method on UIResponder is added via a category, like this:

```
@implementation UIResponder (ActionSending)

-(void)sendAction:(SEL)action withObect:(id)object
{
    UIResponder * target = self ;
    while( self && ![ target respondsToSelector:action ] )
    {
        target = [ target nextResponder ] ;
    }

    [ target performSelector:action withObject:object ] ;
}

@end
```

Your view controller or any parent view or parent view controller that responds to `circleViewTapped:` will have that method invoked when your circle view is tapped.

A note about organizing your views:

I would make a circle view UIView subclass. Instantiate your subclass for each circle to be displayed. To each of those attach a UITapGestureRecognizer. The target of your gesture recognizer is the `-tapped:` method, above.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers are overcomplicating the solution. You don't need gesture recognisers or delegate protocols.

Make your circle drawing view a subclass of UIControl instead of UIView. Then attach your view controller as a target to the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event:

```
[circleView addTarget:self action:@selector(circleTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This will call the `circleTapped:` method on your view controller, with the tapped view as the sender.